# Pivot Date rows into column headers dynamically and repeat unpivoted columns for every date

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

We are trying to create a report on a resultset where For each combination of `OUC,EMP_FIRST_NAME,SURNAME,EIN columns,
ROSTER_IND` and `ABSENCE_CODE and OVERTIME_IND` columns should appear corresponsding to every `ATTENDANCE_DATE`.

We know how to populate pivoted date columns dynamically, but the difficulty here is to populate
`ROSTER_IND and ABSENCE_CODE and OVERTIME_IND` columns as 2nd row corresponding to each `ATTENDANCE_DATE` in 1st row. Kindly help.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_PIVOT 
   (OUC             VARCHAR2(6), 
    EMP_FIRST_NAME  VARCHAR2(50), 
    SURNAME         VARCHAR2(50), 
    EIN             NUMBER(9) NOT NULL, 
    ATTENDANCE_DATE DATE, 
    ROSTER_IND      VARCHAR2(1), 
    ABSENCE_CODE    VARCHAR2(2), 
    OVERTIME_IND    VARCHAR2(1)
    );

insert into TEST_PIVOT values('ABC123','David','Nick',1234,to_date('18-JUL-19','DD-MON-YY'),NULL,'LL',NULL);
insert into TEST_PIVOT values('ABC123','David','Nick',1234,to_date('19-JUL-19','DD-MON-YY'),NULL,'LL',NULL);
insert into TEST_PIVOT values('ABC123','David','Nick',1234,to_date('20-JUL-19','DD-MON-YY'),'R',NULL,NULL);
insert into TEST_PIVOT values('ABC123','David','Nick',1234,to_date('21-JUL-19','DD-MON-YY'),'R',NULL,NULL);
insert into TEST_PIVOT values('ABC123','David','Nick',1234,to_date('22-JUL-19','DD-MON-YY'),NULL,NULL,'W');
insert into TEST_PIVOT values('ABC123','David','Nick',1234,to_date('23-JUL-19','DD-MON-YY'),NULL,NULL,'W');
insert into TEST_PIVOT values('ABC123','David','Nick',1234,to_date('24-JUL-19','DD-MON-YY'),NULL,'GL','M');
insert into TEST_PIVOT values('ABC123','David','Nick',1234,to_date('25-JUL-19','DD-MON-YY'),'R','GL','M');
insert into TEST_PIVOT values('ABC123','David','Nick',1234,to_date('26-JUL-19','DD-MON-YY'),NULL,NULL,NULL);
insert into TEST_PIVOT values('ABC123','David','Nick',1234,to_date('27-JUL-19','DD-MON-YY'),'R',NULL,'W');

insert into TEST_PIVOT values('ABC789','Jorge','Matt',7890,to_date('18-JUL-19','DD-MON-YY'),NULL,'LL',NULL);
insert into TEST_PIVOT values('ABC789','Jorge','Matt',7890,to_date('19-JUL-19','DD-MON-YY'),'R',NULL,NULL);
insert into TEST_PIVOT values('ABC789','Jorge','Matt',7890,to_date('20-JUL-19','DD-MON-YY'),NULL,'LL',NULL);
insert into TEST_PIVOT values('ABC789','Jorge','Matt',7890,to_date('21-JUL-19','DD-MON-YY'),'R',NULL,NULL);
insert into TEST_PIVOT values('ABC789','Jorge','Matt',7890,to_date('22-JUL-19','DD-MON-YY'),NULL,NULL,'W');
insert into TEST_PIVOT values('ABC789','Jorge','Matt',7890,to_date('23-JUL-19','DD-MON-YY'),NULL,NULL,'W');
insert into TEST_PIVOT values('ABC789','Jorge','Matt',7890,to_date('24-JUL-19','DD-MON-YY'),NULL,'GL','M');
insert into TEST_PIVOT values('ABC789','Jorge','Matt',7890,to_date('25-JUL-19','DD-MON-YY'),'R','GL','M');
insert into TEST_PIVOT values('ABC789','Jorge','Matt',7890,to_date('26-JUL-19','DD-MON-YY'),NULL,NULL,NULL);
insert into TEST_PIVOT values('ABC789','Jorge','Matt',7890,to_date('27-JUL-19','DD-MON-YY'),'R',NULL,'W');

insert into TEST_PIVOT values('ABC456','Tailor','Henry',4567,to_date('18-JUL-19','DD-MON-YY'),NULL,'LL',NULL);
insert into TEST_PIVOT values('ABC456','Tailor','Henry',4567,to_date('19-JUL-19','DD-MON-YY'),NULL,NULL,NULL);
insert into TEST_PIVOT values('ABC456','Tailor','Henry',4567,to_date('20-JUL-19','DD-MON-YY'),'R',NULL,NULL);
insert into TEST_PIVOT values('ABC456','Tailor','Henry',4567,to_date('21-JUL-19','DD-MON-YY'),'R',NULL,NULL);
insert into TEST_PIVOT values('ABC456','Tailor','Henry',4567,to_date('22-JUL-19','DD-MON-YY'),NULL,NULL,'W');
insert into TEST_PIVOT values('ABC456','Tailor','Henry',4567,to_date('23-JUL-19','DD-MON-YY'),NULL,NULL,'W');
insert into TEST_PIVOT values('ABC456','Tailor','Henry',4567,to_date('24-JUL-19','DD-MON-YY'),NULL,'GL','M');
insert into TEST_PIVOT values('ABC456','Tailor','Henry',4567,to_date('25-JUL-19','DD-MON-YY'),'R','GL','M');
insert into TEST_PIVOT values('ABC456','Tailor','Henry',4567,to_date('26-JUL-19','DD-MON-YY'),NULL,NULL,NULL);
insert into TEST_PIVOT values('ABC456','Tailor','Henry',4567,to_date('27-JUL-19','DD-MON-YY'),'R',NULL,'W');
```

Need to create report as below.

```
18-Jul-19   18-Jul-19   18-Jul-19   19-Jul-19   19-Jul-19   19-Jul-19   20-Jul-19   20-Jul-19   20-Jul-19   21-Jul-19   21-Jul-19   21-Jul-19   ...

ROSTER_IND  ABSENCE_CODE    OVERTIME_IND    ROSTER_IND  ABSENCE_CODE    OVERTIME_IND    ROSTER_IND  ABSENCE_CODE    OVERTIME_IND    ROSTER_IND  ABSENCE_CODE    OVERTIME_IND    ...
ABC123  David   Nick    1234             LL         LL      R           R           
ABC789  Jorge   Matt    7890             LL     R               LL      R           
ABC456  Tailor  Henry   4567             LL                 R           R
```

Comment: there's no dynamic option with plain SQL except pivot with `xml`. You can look up for it. Otherwise need to use PL/SQL with hassle :)

Answer (score 0):

If you found the way to dynamically build list of dates then you can probably dynamically alias them properly in pivot clause. But if you insist on separate row then create header-like rows, union them with your data and then pivot, like here:

```
with 
  params(d1, d2) as (select date '2019-07-18', date '2019-07-27' from dual),
  header(dt, roster_ind, absence_code, overtime_ind) as (
    select to_char(d1 + level - 1, 'dd'), 
           'ROSTER_IND', 'ABSENCE_CODE', 'OVERTIME_IND' 
      from params connect by level - 1 <= d2 - d1 ),
  data as (
    select ouc, emp_first_name, surname, ein, to_char(attendance_date, 'dd') dt, 
           roster_ind, absence_code, overtime_ind 
      from test_pivot join params on attendance_date between d1 and d2
    union all 
    select null, null, null, null, dt, roster_ind, absence_code, overtime_ind 
      from header )
select * 
  from data
  pivot (max(roster_ind) ri, max(absence_code) ac, max(overtime_ind) oi 
         for dt in (18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27))
  order by ouc nulls first
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6b8500fc8155fdb42df88ff33f746757)</sup>**

`params` is where we define date range, `header` recursively creates dates from this range plus header strings, `data` is simply union of your filtered table and headers, last part pivots `data` and `order by` puts header row at the top.